# Get List<object> from sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf

```
public List<Menu> Getmonan()
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RestaurantConnection"].ConnectionString;
        List<Menu> menulist = new List<Menu>();
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Getmenu", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                menu.Tenmon = reader["TenMon"].ToString();
                menu.Loaimon = reader["LoaiMon"].ToString();
                menulist.Add(menu);
            }

        }

        return menulist;
    }
```

My procedure and sql result:

[image: My procedure and sql result]

My WCF test client result:
[image: My WCF test client result]
What wrong with my code? Why do I get same dish in menulist?

Comment: You need to make a new menu each time you read a new row in your while loop

Comment: You keep assigning to the properties of the same menu item, and then repeatedly add that same item to the list. Do something like this instead: `while(reader.Read())
            {
                menulist.Add(new Menu { Tenmon = reader["TenMon"].ToString(), Loaimon = reader["LoaiMon"].ToString()) };
            }`

Comment: @BugFinder thks it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the guys and I have pointed out

you need a new menu for each item in your list, otherwise you're updating the same item, but repeatedly adding it to the list so you end up with multiple copies of the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create new menu into the loop.

You're basically creating one object which you change several times in the loop and then add it several times to a list. It results in a list where all the elements is the same piece of data.

```
public List<Menu> Getmonan()
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RestaurantConnection"].ConnectionString;
        List<Menu> menulist = new List<Menu>();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Getmenu", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                Menu menu = new Menu();
                menu.Tenmon = reader["TenMon"].ToString();
                menu.Loaimon = reader["LoaiMon"].ToString();
                menulist.Add(menu);
            }

        }

        return menulist;
    }
```

Comment: You could have added an explanation that the Add method simply saves a reference to the Menu object - it does not create a copy of that object (unless it is a struct or int/double/etc). So the same reference is stored multiple times & all entries will appear the same - which is the last details stored.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create multiple objects instead of overwriting the old one:

```
public List<Menu> Getmonan()
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RestaurantConnection"].ConnectionString;
    List<Menu> menulist = new List<Menu>();
    // Menu menu = new Menu();  // <--- remove this!!
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Getmenu", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            Menu menu = new Menu();   // <--- put it here...
            menu.Tenmon = reader["TenMon"].ToString();
            menu.Loaimon = reader["LoaiMon"].ToString();
            menulist.Add(menu);
        }

    }

    return menulist;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
public List<Menu> Getmonan()
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RestaurantConnection"].ConnectionString;

    List<Menu> menulist = new List<Menu>();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Getmenu", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
        {
            while(sdr.Read())
            {
                Menu menu = new Menu()
                {
                    Tenmon = sdr.GetString(Column Index);
                    Loaimon = sdr.GetString(Column Index);
                };
                menulist.Add(menu);
            }
        }
    }
    return menulist;
}
```

Comment: oh and a sdr.close() after the while

Comment: The `SqlDataReader` should get disposed too.

Comment: When the `using` clause for the `SqlConnection` is done, it calls `Dispose` on the `conn`. Digging around the [documention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326261(v=vs.71).aspx), this is equivalent to calling ``Dispose(true)``, which disposes all objects referenced by the connection. 

So actually, I think the "using" tag around the reader is superflous.