# Having issue with "unexpected token u in json at position 0"

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I'm converting a DataTable to JSON via below code:

```
public string DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet(DataTable table)
{
    string JSONString = string.Empty;
    JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);
    return JSONString;
}
```

The issue seems to be that this is not returning proper JSON. The value of  JSONString is:

```
"{\"DataTable.RemotingVersion\":{\"Major\":2,\"Minor\":0,\"Build\":-1,\"Revision\":-1,\"MajorRevision\":-1,\"MinorRevision\":-1},\"XmlSchema\":\"<?xml version=\\\"1.0\\\" encoding=\\\"utf-16\\\"?>\\r\\n<xs:schema xmlns=\\\"\\\" xmlns:xs=\\\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\\\" xmlns:msdata=\\\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata\\\">\\r\\n  <xs:element name=\\\"Table1\\\">\\r\\n    <xs:complexType>\\r\\n      <xs:sequence>\\r\\n        <xs:element name=\\\"ID\\\" type=\\\"xs:int\\\" msdata:targetNamespace=\\\"\\\" minOccurs=\\\"0\\\" />\\r\\n        <xs:element name=\\\"ImageURL\\\" type=\\\"xs:string\\\" msdata:targetNamespace=\\\"\\\" minOccurs=\\\"0\\\" />\\r\\n        <xs:element name=\\\"Price\\\" type=\\\"xs:decimal\\\" msdata:targetNamespace=\\\"\\\" minOccurs=\\\"0\\\" />\\r\\n        <xs:element name=\\\"Description\\\" type=\\\"xs:string\\\" msdata:targetNamespace=\\\"\\\" minOccurs=\\\"0\\\" />\\r\\n        <xs:element name=\\\"UploadDate\\\" type=\\\"xs:dateTime\\\" msdata:targetNamespace=\\\"\\\" minOccurs=\\\"0\\\" />\\r\\n        <xs:element name=\\\"ExpDate\\\" type=\\\"xs:dateTime\\\" msdata:targetNamespace=\\\"\\\" minOccurs=\\\"0\\\" />\\r\\n        <xs:element name=\\\"Status\\\" type=\\\"xs:string\\\" msdata:targetNamespace=\\\"\\\" minOccurs=\\\"0\\\" />\\r\\n      </xs:sequence>\\r\\n    </xs:complexType>\\r\\n  </xs:element>\\r\\n  <xs:element name=\\\"tmpDataSet\\\" msdata:IsDataSet=\\\"true\\\" msdata:MainDataTable=\\\"Table1\\\" msdata:UseCurrentLocale=\\\"true\\\">\\r\\n    <xs:complexType>\\r\\n      <xs:choice minOccurs=\\\"0\\\" maxOccurs=\\\"unbounded\\\" />\\r\\n    </xs:complexType>\\r\\n  </xs:element>\\r\\n</xs:schema>\",\"XmlDiffGram\":\"<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata=\\\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata\\\" xmlns:diffgr=\\\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1\\\">\\r\\n  <tmpDataSet>\\r\\n    <Table1 diffgr:id=\\\"Table11\\\" msdata:rowOrder=\\\"0\\\">\\r\\n      <ID>1</ID>\\r\\n      <ImageURL>https://i.imgur.com/S59HjAe.jpg </ImageURL>\\r\\n      <Price>123.0000</Price>\\r\\n      <Description>123</Description>\\r\\n      <UploadDate>2019-04-19T08:30:56.913-05:00</UploadDate>\\r\\n      <ExpDate>1900-01-01T00:00:00-06:00</ExpDate>\\r\\n      <Status>New</Status>\\r\\n    </Table1>\\r\\n  </tmpDataSet>\\r\\n</diffgr:diffgram>\"}"
```

To my understanding, the result should not include the majority of the beginning of this string (Revision, XML Schema, Data Types of the Columns, etc).

Can anyone explain why I'm getting additional information after converting the DT? I believe the additional information is causing the "unexpected token u in json at position 0" error. I'd appreciate any help, thank you.

EDIT: The javascript code utilizing this is:

```
function GetItemsList() {
    try {
        $('#Products').html('');
        var items = '';
        document.getElementById("Products").innerHTML = ""
        var i = 0;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Home/UseGetItems',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                var ItemData = JSON.parse(result.Data);

                if (ItemData.length > 0) {
                    for (i; i < ItemData.length; i++) {
                        document.getElementById("Products").innerHTML += '<div class="w3 - col l3 s6"><div class="w3 - container"><img src="' + ItemData[i].ImageURL + '" style="width:100%"><p>' + ItemData[i].Description + '<br><b>' + ItemData[i].Price + '</b></p></div></div>';
                    }
                    $('#Products').append(items);
                }
            },
        });

    } catch (e) {

    }
}
```

EDIT 2: Rest of the C# is:

```
public ActionResult UseGetItems()

{
    jsonMessage result = new jsonMessage();

    var ItemsList = GetItems();

    return Json(new
    {
        Data = ItemsList,
        result = true,
    });

}

public string GetItems()
{
    var Items = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string Connection = "Data Source=TEST; Initial Catalog=TEST;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=TEST;Password=TEST"; //ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConn"].ConnectionString;
        string Query = "SELECT * FROM [TEST] WHERE [Status] <> 'CLOSED'";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, conn)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.Text
            };
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@this", "value"));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();
        };
        Items = DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }

    return Items;
}
```

@briosheje the result of `console.log(result);` is

```
Object
data: "{"DataTable.RemotingVersion":{"Major":2,"Minor":0,"Build":-1,"Revision":-1,"MajorRevision":-1,"MinorRevision":-1},"XmlSchema":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n<xs:schema xmlns=\"\" xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:msdata=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata\">\r\n  <xs:element name=\"Table1\">\r\n    <xs:complexType>\r\n      <xs:sequence>\r\n        <xs:element name=\"ID\" type=\"xs:int\" msdata:targetNamespace=\"\" minOccurs=\"0\" />\r\n        <xs:element name=\"ImageURL\" type=\"xs:string\" msdata:targetNamespace=\"\" minOccurs=\"0\" />\r\n        <xs:element name=\"Price\" type=\"xs:decimal\" msdata:targetNamespace=\"\" minOccurs=\"0\" />\r\n        <xs:element name=\"Description\" type=\"xs:string\" msdata:targetNamespace=\"\" minOccurs=\"0\" />\r\n        <xs:element name=\"UploadDate\" type=\"xs:dateTime\" msdata:targetNamespace=\"\" minOccurs=\"0\" />\r\n        <xs:element name=\"ExpDate\" type=\"xs:dateTime\" msdata:targetNamespace=\"\" minOccurs=\"0\" />\r\n        <xs:element name=\"Status\" type=\"xs:string\" msdata:targetNamespace=\"\" minOccurs=\"0\" />\r\n      </xs:sequence>\r\n    </xs:complexType>\r\n  </xs:element>\r\n  <xs:element name=\"tmpDataSet\" msdata:IsDataSet=\"true\" msdata:MainDataTable=\"Table1\" msdata:UseCurrentLocale=\"true\">\r\n    <xs:complexType>\r\n      <xs:choice minOccurs=\"0\" maxOccurs=\"unbounded\" />\r\n    </xs:complexType>\r\n  </xs:element>\r\n</xs:schema>","XmlDiffGram":"<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata\" xmlns:diffgr=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1\">\r\n  <tmpDataSet>\r\n    <Table1 diffgr:id=\"Table11\" msdata:rowOrder=\"0\">\r\n      <ID>1</ID>\r\n      <ImageURL>https://i.imgur.com/S59HjAe.jpg </ImageURL>\r\n      <Price>123.0000</Price>\r\n      <Description>123</Description>\r\n      <UploadDate>2019-04-19T08:30:56.913-05:00</UploadDate>\r\n      <ExpDate>1900-01-01T00:00:00-06:00</ExpDate>\r\n      <Status>New</Status>\r\n    </Table1>\r\n  </tmpDataSet>\r\n</diffgr:diffgram>"}"
result: true
__proto__: Object
```

EDIT 3: If I change the C# to be a DT being returned (instead of serializing there), like this:

```
public DataTable GetItems()
{
    DataTable Items;

    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string Connection = "Data Source=TEST; Initial Catalog=TEST;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=TEST;Password=TEST"; //ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConn"].ConnectionString;
        string Query = "SELECT * FROM [TEST] WHERE [Status] <> 'CLOSED'";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, conn)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.Text
            };
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@this", "value"));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();
        };
        Items = dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }

    return Items;
}
```

Then the result of `var ItemData = JSON.parse(result.data);` gives the error:

```
Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

EDIT 4:

```
    public class jsonMessage
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string MessageList { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48405013/2141621) for how what you want should be done

Comment: @FragEden - I'm confused as to what your question is currently.  Might you please roll up your edits into a single simplified question?